# Converting an array of primitives to List using Arrays.asList

Tags: java

I have this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      double[] a = new double[2];

      for( double d : Arrays.asList(a)) 
            System.out.println(d); 
  }

}
```

Output:

```
$ javac Test1.java 
Test1.java:9: error: incompatible types
      for( double d : Arrays.asList(a)) 
                                   ^
  required: double
  found:    double[]
1 error
```

Why am I getting an error here?

and

**What is the meaning of the error? What is it telling me ?**

Comment: Because `Arrays#asList` works on `Object` types, as your headline already says. However, you don't need `Arrays#asList` in that case anyways, as you can iterate over the array.

Comment: You have an array of doubles?, why not just iterate over that array: `for(final double d: a){ System.out.println(d);}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error here because when you work with the function which accepts varargs, this functions creates behind a scene a new array of objects you passed in it. So, `Arrays.asList(1,2,3)` gets, in fact, *an array of integers*.
When you pass in an array of integers, `Arrays.asList()` creates *an array of arrays of integers* behind the scene. That's why you can't iterate over it with the following loop:

```
for( double d : Arrays.asList(a))
```

Try to change it like so:

```
for(double[] d : Arrays.asList(a))
```

And you'll see that `d` is, in fact, reference to the array you passed into the `Arrays.asList()` - `a`.

Comment: thanks for mentioning the general rule on how functions with varargs work.

Answer (score 4):

In Java, Collections like `List` can only refer to *reference types*.  `double[]` is an array of primitives (but the array itself is a reference type).  Because of that, `Arrays.asList` is trying to create a `List<double[]>`, and if you try to for-each over that list you are going to get items that are `double[]` arrays and not individual `double` values.

However, you can still use a for-each loop over primitive arrays:

```
for (double d : a) {
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

Comment: @abc It is telling you, that you need `Double[]` instead of `double[]`.

Comment: @abc edited; do the new second & third sentences explain it to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 2):

The variable `a` has type `double[]`, not `double`.

Therefore, calling `Arrays.asList(a)` will produce a `List<double[]>`, not a `List<double>`. In other words, every element in the list will be an array of `double` values, not a `double` value.

Thus, iterating over such a list will not extract the 2 `double` values in the example array `a`, but a single `double[]` value, i.e. the array `a` itself.

This is easy to verify by running the following statements:

```
a = new double[2];
b = Arrays.asList(a);
System.out.println(b.size());
```

The above code will print `1`, verifying that `b` is a list with only 1 element, the array `a`.

To iterate over the elements of `a` itself, one can run directly

```
for (double d : a) { 
    System.out.println(d);
}
```

To create a list of all the double values from `a`, each value has to be converted to a `Double` object before added to the list, e.g.:

```
List<Double> c = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (double d : a) {
    c.add(d); // Java automatically converts from double to Double
}
```

Comment: You could mention, that this behavior only occurs with arrays of primitives. Arrays of reference types are treated correclty.

Comment: Sure, but the question was about arrays of primitives. Thanks and +1 for the remark, though, it is useful to have it in the discussion. :-)